# Comment out one line of many files with sed

Tags: sed, replace

I need to comment out a line of many files on one path. The line reads

```
input_types = ['text']
```

and I need to replace it by

```
#input_types = ['text']
```

I want to do something like

```
sed -i 's/input_types/#input_types/g' path/to/files/*
```

but that would change all instances of input_types and I don't want that.

I also tried

```
sed -i 's/input_types = ['text']/#input_types = ['text']/g' path/to/files/*
```

but it didn't work

How can I change only that specific instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You last try was quite good, but two things have to be changed:

- You use single quotes to enclose your expression, but single quotes are also part of the expression -- that gets confusing. In this case it's better to use double quotes for enclosing the expression, instead.
- The `[ ]` brackets have to be escaped with backslashes: `\[ \]`

So, if you change the line to

```
sed -i "s/input_types = \['text'\]/#input_types = \['text'\]/g" /path/to/files/*
```

it should work.

Comment: You don't need to repeat the complete pattern, you can use `&` in the replacement string: `sed -i "s/input_types = \['text'\]/#&/g" /path/to/files/*`.